# How organize layers in a project using Entity Framework?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, service-layer

I have a dilemma about organizing my projects. I'm building an application for sending newsletters. I divided it into three projects in my solution: `Newsletter.UI` (WPF), `Newsletter.DAL` and `Newsletter.Services`. In `Newsletter.DAL` there are classes representing entities generating by EF enhanced in additional files (they are partial classes) - overriden `ToString()`. In `Newsletter.UI` there is of cource WPF project for presentation. The problem for me begins with `Newsletter.Services`.

For now I created `MailingListService.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newsletter.DAL;

namespace Newsletter.Services
{
    public class MailingListService
    {
        private NewsletterEntities _context;

        public MailingListService()
        {
            _context = new NewsletterEntities();
        }

        public List<string> GetAllMailingListsNames()
        {
            var query = from m in _context.MailingLists select new { m.Name };
            List<string> names = new List<string>();
            foreach (var m in query)
                names.Add(m.Name);
            return names;
        }

        public List<MailingList> GetAllMailingLists()
        {
            var query = from m in _context.MailingLists select m;
            return query.ToList();       
        }
    }
}
```

`MessageService.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newsletter.DAL;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Newsletter.Services
{
    public class MessageService
    {
        private NewsletterEntities _context;

        public MessageService()
        {
            _context = new NewsletterEntities();
        }

        public List<Message> GetAllMessages()
        {
            return (from m in _context.Messages select m).ToList();
        }

        public static Message GetMessageByID(int id)
        {
            using (NewsletterEntities context = new NewsletterEntities())
            {
                Message message = (from m in context.Messages where m.MessageID == id select m).FirstOrDefault();
                return message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`RecipientService.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newsletter.DAL;

namespace Newsletter.Services
{
    public class RecipientService
    {
        private NewsletterEntities _context;
        public RecipientService()
        {
            _context = new NewsletterEntities();
        }
        public void addRecipient(Recipient newRecipient)
        {
            _context.Recipients.AddObject(newRecipient);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this gets problematic. When I open a window for creating a recipient, I create a `MailingListService` instance to load mailing lists' names. Then when I try to create a new `Recipient`, I create a `RecipientService` instance and try to add a recipient. I get an error that I cannot use the context in different places.

How to solve this? Is my approach bad? What should it be (what should be in Services)? I don't want to get into such errors in future. I don't want to learn the MVVM approach now, I need to do this more or less the way I am doing it.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are seeing? And on what line does the error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several approaches are possible:

1. Use one context instance for a business transaction. The context should be created outside the services and be passed to the services through their methods or their constructors. This would require a layer of higher level services (or façades) that orchestrate the lower level services (like the ones you've got now). An IoC container could help you create and inject a context with a life cycle that is bound to that of a façade service instance.
2. Detach/attach. In your `AddRecipient` method first detach the recipient (after checking if it is attached) and attach it to the current context. However: now the unit of work is split up between 2 context instances and you'll need a `TransactionScope` to keep it transactionally sound.
3. Aggregate at a higher level, e.g. by creating a `MailService` that deals with mailing lists, messages, and recipients.
4. A mixed approach. Service with their own context instance and (preferably stateless) services that have methods with a context argument in their method signatures (like `public Recipient AddRecipient(NewsletterEntities context, string name, string email)`. (By passing name etc. the service is made responsible for creating new `Recipient` objects or returning existing ones if they're already there).

Just a few thoughts :).